# Музыкальный плеер на android

Tags: android, аудио

Нужно, чтобы при проигрывании песни, когда кто-то позвонит, песня останавливалась и начинала играть при конце разговора. Суть в том, что реализовал так, как было в документации. Когда мне звонят, оно работает, когда я звоню, песня останавливается (вызывается LOSS_TRANSIENT), но после окончания разговора не запускается.
AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN не срабатывает.

```
AudioManager     audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, 
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
................................................    
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener onAudioFocusChangeListener=new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                switch (focusChange) {
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                        Log.e("FOCUS", "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS, turning FM off");
                        pause();
                        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener);
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                        pause();
                        Log.e("FOCUS", "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                        pause();
                        Log.e("FOCUS", "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                        play();
                        Log.e("FOCUS", "AudioFocus: received AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("FOCUS", "Unknown audio focus change code " + focusChange);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Можно еще попробовать использовать [PhoneStateListener][1].


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: Да, но не советуют. Мол, что нужно дополнительный permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немножко неправильно делаете. Почитайте [первоисточник](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html).

Смысл в том, что вы не уважаете правила получения аудиофокуса.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `onAudioFocusChange()` вызывается только при внешних запросах.
При вызове из приложения `request/abandonAudioFocus()` листенер не запускается.